# How do I assign a title to each of the histograms I have posted at the same time?

Tags: pandas, plotting, matplotlib

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,7, sharey=True)

df2.loc[df2.country == 'BR','date_created'].hist(xrot=90,bins=30,ax=axes[0],figsize=(20,4));
df2.loc[df2.country == 'CH','date_created'].hist(xrot=90,bins=30,ax=axes[1],);
df2.loc[df2.country == 'CL','date_created'].hist(xrot=90,bins=30,ax=axes[2])
df2.loc[df2.country == 'DE','date_created'].hist(xrot=90,bins=30,ax=axes[3])
df2.loc[df2.country == 'CO','date_created'].hist(xrot=90,bins=30,ax=axes[4])
df2.loc[df2.country == 'GR','date_created'].hist(xrot=90,bins=30,ax=axes[5])
df2.loc[df2.country == 'JP','date_created'].hist(xrot=90,bins=30,ax=axes[6])
plt.xticks(size = 12);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the axes variables you have, which is a numpy.ndarray of size 7

```
axes[0].set_title('Title for Fig. 1') #change title for first histogram
axes[1].set_title('Title for Fig. 2') #change title for second histogram
axes[2].set_title('Title for Fig. 3') #change title for third histogram
```